# Bot SDK with facebook channel - outside Azure deployment

Tags: facebook, azure, botframework

I have a question related to channels and using bot SDK outside azure, Is there a sample code which shows how to connect the bot SDK with facebook channel without deploying it to Azure? ex: running as a standalone node app and connect facebook callback?. The reason is I [checked this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/demo-facebook/app.js)  and inside the logic I can't see it has a facebook channel specific connector is used. So my question is does bot SDK core automatically understand how to interpret messages coming from any channel (in this case facebook) or does this conversion done by the channel connectors only available in Azure deployment?

I would like to use botframework mainly because it has, dialogs and session state already implemented instead of I re-do it again. But I want to use it outside Azure and with facebook channel

Comment: One option is you can deploy your app anywhere, but create a `bot registration` in azure. There you can specify the URL of your app. I personally don't know how you can create NO AZURE app, as the facebook webhook and its verification token are supplied in the bot registration page, and not in the bot code.

Comment: @MasterChief thanks for the reply, That's the part I don't understand why the part of the bot framework is given and the connectors are tightly coupled with the Azure platform. (There might be a way and that's why I want an answer from a person who has done it without Azure), Question is are these different channel connectors are available us to integrate manually, otherwise no point using bot framework as it is tightly coupled with Azure platform

Comment: The connector services are not open source.  You would need to write your own Facebook Connector Service in order to use the Microsoft Bot Framework with Facebook Messenger without and Azure subscription.